# How to run a .sql script (from file) in Java and return a ResultSet using Spring?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc

How to run a .sql script (from file) in Java and return a `ResultSet` using Spring?

I have a program that runs `SQL` queries on a database that return `ResultSet` which I later process and use the data in my classes. I am currently using `JDBC` with the scripts inside the Java program.

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("some script on multiple lines");
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query.toString());
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

I want to move the SQL queries outside of the Java program to .sql files, but I want to keep all the program logic from the `executeQuery` statements on. This means I want to have the queries return a ResultSet.

I looked to several methods like using a `ScriptRunner`, using Spring `JdbcTestUtils.executeSqlScript` or reading the .sql file using a `BufferReader` and then passing the string to my statement. The `ScriptRunner` and the Spring `JdbcTestUtils.executeSqlScript` seem to not return a ResultSet, or I couldn't find the proper implementation. I want to stay away of the `BufferReader` method since it will require text parsing and a lot of exceptions to handle.

```
ScriptRunner scriptRunner = new ScriptRunner(connection, true, true);
scriptRunner.runScript(new FileReader("script.sql"));
```

The `runScript` method returns void. Same does the `Spring` implementation:

```
MysqlDataSource ds = new MysqlDataSource();
ds.setServerName("host");
ds.setUser("user");
ds.setPassword("password");

JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);

Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("script.sql");
JdbcTestUtils.executeSqlScript(jdbcTemplate, resource, true);
```

I looked thorough the `Spring` api but couldn't find something similar to what I want.
Is there a way to load a script from file and then run it so it returns a `ResultSet` using `Spring`? I would prefer using `Spring` since it is actively mantained.

Answer (score 6):

I found a way to do it using Spring:

```
MysqlDataSource ds = new MysqlDataSource();
ds.setServerName("host");
ds.setUser("user");
ds.setPassword("password");

JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("script.sql"));
LineNumberReader fileReader = new LineNumberReader(in);
String query = JdbcTestUtils.readScript(fileReader);
```

Now we will use the `jdbcTemplate.query` to query the database using the .sql script we read. The `ResultSet` required will be passed as parameter to the `extractData` of `ResultSetExtractor` implementation or to the `mapRow` of the `RowMapper` implementation. So the processing of the `ResultSet` will be done in the `extractData` or `mapRow` implementation and we will return the Collection/Object we need

```
List<YourClass> result = jdbcTemplate.query(query, new RowMapper<YourClass>() {
            @Override
            public YourClass mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
                // processing of the ResultSet
                return result;
            }
        });
```

or

```
YourClass object = jdbcTemplate.query(query, new ResultSetExtractor<YourClass>() {
            @Override
            public YourClass extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                // processing of the ResultSet
                return result;
            }
        });
```

Of course, using the last implementation you can return any object you want, even a collection of objects.

Comment: The problem of using **JdbcTestUtils** is that you must package the test jars into your deployed application.

Comment: It is now deprecated, you should use: ScriptUtils.readScript()

Comment: ScriptUtils.readScript() is also now deprecated. What's the latest solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would use property file to store sql queries.

For example:

```
person-save=insert into person values....
person-get-all=select * from person....
```

With that you can read the statements from the file

In the context:

```
<util:properties id="sqlProps" location="classpath:sqlProps.properties" />
```

In the DAO:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sqlProps")
private Properties sqlProps;
```

...

```
String query = sqlProps.getProperty("person-get-all");
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

If you want to execute all the statements in a file, you have to implement that yourself. Just loop over the properties and execute them one by one. You will need some flag to determinate if its select or update/delete statement.
Loop over properties:

```
Enumeration e = props.propertyNames();

    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
      String key = (String) e.nextElement();
      String query= props.getProperty(key);
    }
```

Comment: Isn't this similar to using a `BufferReader` to read the file? I will imply doing some parsing on the file. Do you know any implementation using `Spring`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this using `commons-io`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
//...
String sqlQuery = IOUtils.toString((new ClassPathResource("me.sql")).getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset());
```

Comment: import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>